How to install MELPA in Emacs?
Question: How do I install the MELPA repository?

I was told to add the following to my .emacs file.
(require 'package)
;; Any add to list for package-archives (to add marmalade or melpa) goes here
(add-to-list 'package-archives 
    '("MELPA" .
      "http://melpa.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)

However, I cannot find said file. My ~/.emacs.d/ looks like the following:
usr@computer:~$ ls ~/.emacs.d/
auto-save-list  elpa
usr@computer:~$

Where do I add the repository for MELPA? Is this the correct text to add?
Thank you so much for any help you can provide.

Also execute
(package-refresh-contents)

Then you'll see the directory ~/.emacs.d/elpa/archives/MELPA.
